# Error establishing database connection during installation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, installation

I have a site that is going to use Wordpress within the main server www directory as it's blog engine. I know for a fact that the credentials are correct because I have no problem logging into PHPMyAdmin with them, so I'm almost positive that this is a server configuration issue. Has anyone else encountered this, and if so how do you resolve the issue. If it helps at all the site is hosted on Media Temple.

Comment: You could try providing more information, such as the error, when it occurs, etc. Make sure to scrub your credentials if they appear anywhere in this data.

Comment: Can someone please just be constructive here, I ask in wordpress.stackexchange.com, I'm told it's off topic; that it's a SQL question. I can accept this as legitimate. But if you are going to downvote have the courage to explain why. And the error message IS in the title itself "Error establishing a database connection". Oh wait, when occurs is in the title also "during installation".

Comment: What error message are you receiving? Does the DB exist?

Comment: @k4t434sis - It appears to be a poorly researched question is all. You haven't presented any failed solutions you've tried, proposed solutions, whether or not you've checked media temple's knowledge base, etc. If you provide more information about what's happening, we can probably help.

Comment: The database exists, the username and password are correct (henceforth being able to successfully log into phpmyadmin). I am quite familiar with Wordpress and have never had this error unless I had stupid fingers that day and passed WP a typo.

Comment: I've read into Media Temple's support section to no avail. And since I do not have login credentials to Media Temple I cannot receive any live help. I'm dreadfully sorry I cannot provide anymore details. This is an ongoing thing with my company, 'We want this finished, but you can only have the bare minimum access neccesary to accomplish your job'. Very typical from what I hear.

Comment: Just logging into phpMyAdmin through a hosting company does not mean you have the correct credentials for a database. For example, my hosting provider keeps all logins the same across cPanel / phpMyAdmin, but I have separate usernames / passwords for my databases.

Also, it looks like they offer one-click install:
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/913/Installing+WordPress+using+the+1-Click+Application+Tool

Comment: Ack! You're right. Somehow looked right over this http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/4/Why+can%27t+I+connect+to+my+MySQL+database+from+PHP%3F#gs, thanks guys. Sorry for being a bit snippy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just logging into phpMyAdmin through a hosting company does not mean you have the correct credentials for a database. For example, my hosting provider keeps all logins the same across cPanel / phpMyAdmin, but I have separate usernames / passwords for my databases.

You need to make sure that you:

1. Have a database created for the Wordpress installation
2. Have a database user (MySQL?) and password that is granted permission to access that database

From there, you will most likely choose 'localhost' as your database's host and enter your MySQL username and password.

This is pretty detailed and should walk you through the installation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Or it looks like they offer one-click install:
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/913/Installing+WordPress+using+the+1-Click+Application+Tool

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget that Media Temple shared hosting servers do not allow use of localhost. You need to go into your panel to find your server name if it is not a DV.

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/4/Why+can't+I+connect+to+my+MySQL+database+from+PHP%3F#gs